# iOS development: Accessing Core Data from a second ViewController

Tags: iphone, core-data

I created a Navigation based project and checked the "Use Core Data"-checkbox. I'm able to insert new objects from the RootViewController. I got a second ViewController (SecondViewController) that is going to add data from textfields to Core Data, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

I tried to add the relevant code (Core Data-code generated by Xcode at project creation) from RootViewController to SecondViewController, but the app terminates due to "uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Event' ", where "Event" is the entity generated by the system when the project was created.

The code is almost identical to what you get by creating a new Navigation based project with the "Use Core Data"-checkbox checked. The only difference is that when you hit the "+"-button, you are brought to another ViewController with one textfield and one button. Upon hitting that button, the data should be created.

I could upload the code, but Xcode generates a lot of code when checking "Use Core Data". It's probably easier to just generate the project.

Any ideas to how I might solve this? In advance, thanks! :-)

Comment: We need to see some code! What do you mean by 'relevant code'?

Comment: are you using the same managedObjectContext across your two controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass your NSManagedObjectContext to your SecondViewController. Be careful to do your insert / delete / update on the main thread, otherwise see how to deal with threading and Core Data : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1

Comment: Passed that along with the NSFetchedResultsController, and it worked. Thanks, mate! Appreciate that! :-)